# VSFTPD how chroot not chrooted users in /home?

Tags: ftp, chroot, vsftpd

I need to `chroot` all local users to their home directories, but one user should have access to all user directories. If I put `admin_user` in `chroot_list_file` he has access for whole file system. I want to restrict access for him only to `/home`, but when he logs in to ftp server his default directory should be `/home/admin_user`. How  can achieve that?
I have vsftpd installation with following config:

```
# /etc/vsftpd/vsftpd.conf
anonymous_enable=NO
local_enable=YES
write_enable=YES
local_umask=002
dirmessage_enable=YES
xferlog_enable=YES
dual_log_enable=YES
connect_from_port_20=YES
xferlog_std_format=YES
chroot_local_user=YES
chroot_list_enable=YES
chroot_list_file=/etc/vsftpd/chroot_list
listen=YES
pam_service_name=vsftpd
userlist_enable=YES
tcp_wrappers=YES
max_clients=0
max_per_ip=0

# /etc/vsftpd/chroot_list
admin_user
```

Answer (score 2):

You either use VSFTP's chroot() ability to restrict users to their home directories, or not.

If you don't then whole filesystem is exposed and you can only rely on having the correct file system permissions to protect your non-public data.

Having said that, vsftp does have a option to (somewhat) restrict the users movements with the `deny_file` directive:

```
 deny_file
          This option can be used to set  a  pattern  for  filenames  (and
          directory names etc.) which should not be accessible in any way.
          The affected items  are  not  hidden,  but  any  attempt  to  do
          anything  to  them  (download,  change  into  directory,  affect
          something within directory etc.) will be denied. This option  is
          very simple, and should not be used for serious access control -
          the filesystem's  permissions  should  be  used  in  preference.
          However,  this  option  may  be  useful ... ...
```

Create the deny_file e.g. `ls -d /*/ |grep -v home > /etc/vsftpd/forbidden_path`

Best to restrict the `deny_file` so it only applies to  your `admin_user` and not all users:

Add the `user_config_dir=/etc/vsftpd/user.overrides/` directive to the main `vsftpd.conf` configuration and create the user specific override:

```
# /etc/vsftpd/user.overrides/admin_user
# admin_user is excluded from chroot() but restrict his access to /home
deny_file=/etc/vsftpd/forbidden_path
```

and restart the ftp server and test of the behavior is as expected.